# How to access events that are data-bound to element in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have date control that looks like this.

```
<div class="OnTheMoveFormTextBoxContainer">
                       <input data-bind="value: formatDateTime(ko.unwrap(Started)), css: { validationElement: validateItem(Started, 'Started') }, event: {
change: function(d, e) {
    if (Started != $(e)[0].target.value &amp;&amp; dateWheelShown == true) {
        $data.Started(dateToISO($(e)[0].target.value,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'));
    }
}
 }, id: 'Started' + '_' + Id()" data-onthemove_dateformat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm" class="Mobile_DateTimePick ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-mini" data-mini="true" name="Started" id="scoller1400844006695" readonly="">
</div>
```

How could I access data-bound event handlers in knockout.js, I this current case `onchange`.

I am looking for something like this: `ko.contextFor($($('.OnTheMoveFormTextBoxContainer')[3]).find('input')[0]).events`

Comment: @CubedEye how is that a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindings`.

Something like (*untested*):

```
 ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindings(
              $($('.OnTheMoveFormTextBoxContainer')[3]).find('input').get(0),
              ko.contextFor($($('.OnTheMoveFormTextBoxContainer')[3]).find('input').get(0).$root
 ).event.change
```

**Update**
Maybe more like:
    var x = $($('.OnTheMoveFormTextBoxContainer')[3]).find('input').get(0);

```
ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindings(x, ko.contextFor(x)).event
```

See this thread [Access knockout binding from child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113503/access-knockout-binding-from-child-element/23134140#23134140)